# how to delete row from tableview without using editmode?

Tags: iphone

hi to all i am new to iphone,in tableview displayed data access from database and provide delete data option when button clicked,my problem is when i clicked that button data delete from database at that time row is not delete from tableview after rerun the program deleteed data don't display it worked correctly but i want delete row from tableview also when button clicked but table not in edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

to delete data from the UITableView without using the UI (edit mode, and edit button)

first, delete the data from your datasource then call

– deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:

give it a nice rowanimation like UITableViewRowAnimationRight and you get a very sexy UX.